# React form validation with react-hook-form and multiple form components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form

I have a form with multiple components and tried to follow steps in this tutorial, to have my inputs validated: [7 Form Components For React Hook Form I Always Use](https://dev.to/theodorusclarence/7-form-components-for-react-hook-form-i-always-use-1ahd)

I just tried with first one, which is name, but validation won't happen. Instead console shoots a message: **form submission canceled because the form is not connected react**

Here is my sandbox: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-dirac-bebdd?file=/components/Form.js)

The form component should manage the overall validations `FormProvider, useForm`on submit, while in my test component I tried to manage the single input validations and error messages. It is important however that Form.js submit button keeps the `onClick={makeContract}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove your `onClick` handler in your `<input type="submit">`

In `react-hook-form`, you should have only one submit handler, which you already had here

`<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}`

the `onSubmit` handler here will only be called if all the fields in your form are valid.

So if you want to call `makeContract` when submitting form, call it inside `onSubmit`

```
  // only called when all fields valid
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    makeContract();
  };
```

[Live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-dew-p56qu?file=/components/Form.js:603-681)